# How can I convert WMV to FLA?

Tags: flash, wmv, fla

I'd like to convert WMV file (windows movie maker) to FLA (flash).

I have Adobe Encore and Adobe Premier, can either one of them be used (if so, than how?).

Or is there free software I can use? that doesn't add any logos and such into the frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is great for that sort of thing (and used by just about everyone doing automatic conversions, apparently [including youtube](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/googles-youtube-uses-ffmpeg/).

Update: Are you sure you want 'FLA" as the output?  Unless you are targeting really old versions of flash, you'll likely be better off encoding to H.264.

I also wanted to add that for an individual video it's a bit of work to use and get good results, but if you're going to use it over and over it's easy because it's so easy to automate.  Even when you are doing your testing it's easy to make a small script/program to encode your test videos with various options and see the results.